# ember.js - use of vendor directory

Tags: ember.js

When I try to reference an asset in `vendor` I get a 404 - would someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

[image]

In attempting to follow the doco (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/ paragraph headed 'Other Assets') I've copied some js/css to the `vendor` directory.

In index.html I've added :

```
<script src="vendor/gmaps.js"></script>
```

When I then run `ember s` the page is rendered but the references to the assets in `vendor` return 404.

I've also tried :

```
 <script src="{{rootURL}}vendor/gmaps.js"></script>
```

with the same result.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building an Ember app, I have never found a good use case to add a `<script>`, `<link>`, or really any tag to the `index.html` file. Anything placed in the appropriate `vendor` folder can be injected/concatenated/compiled into the `vendor.js` file by adding...

```
app.import('vendor/your_vendor_folder/your_vendor_file.js');
```

...to your `ember-cli-build.js` file. This compilation process is further elaborated on right after the "Other Assets" documentation, in the ["Compiling Assets" section](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/#toc_compiling-assets).

> When you're using dependencies that are not included in an addon, you
>   will have to instruct Ember CLI to include your assets in the build.
>   This is done using the asset manifest file ember-cli-build.js. You
>   should only try to import assets located in the bower_components and
>   vendor folders.

Doing so will register that file as a global which can be used in any of your Ember objects. Keep in mind that you might need to edit your `.jshintrc` to remove any JSHint errors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I appreciate it.